# Give access to IOT hub to an external developer in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I need to give access to Azure IoT hub to an external company. How do I do that?

I cant figure out how to add them in Azure active directory, while also trying to restrict their access only to the IOT hub.

Comment: What do you mean by "give access"?  Do you want to allow them to send messages to the IoT Hub or perform administrative tasks in the portal?

Comment: do you know if your instance of Azure uses Azures Active Directory or does it authenticate through an on premise instance of Active Directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to grant others access to the Azure IoT hub and send messages, a simply IoT Hub device client shall be good enough.

I don't see the point of creating some user account in Azure AD.

You can create an new device client either in [Azure Portal](http://portal.azure.com) or with [Device Explorer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/tree/master/tools/DeviceExplorer), either way, you need to share the "connection string" of the device with the external developers, by which they can connect to Azure IoT Hub to send/receive messages using [azure-iot-sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks).

By the way, azure-iot-sdk has multiple platform(windows/linux/mbed, etc...), and multiple language(C#,java,C/C++,python etc...) support. So even with hardware developer, he or she can set things up pretty quickly.

That's how I share my Azure IoT Hub with others and hope it's helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an external user (a user from another Azure AD tenant) to your directory following the instructions documented here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-create-users-external/#add-external-users

Once you've added the external user to the directory, you can choose to grant them access to resources in your Azure subscription (they'll only have access to what you choose to grant them access to) just like you would any other resource.

In the following image, Peter Smith, from Fabrikam, Inc. (peter.smith@fabrikam.com) has been invited as an external user into Contoso Corp's tenant (contoso.com), and can be assigned the "Contributor" role for an IoT Hub:

[image: Granting access for user to IoT hub]

The user, then, simply needs to sign in to the Azure portal (https://portal.azure.com), and switch to your company's Azure AD tenant. In the following image, Peter Smith, who is homed in the fabrikam.com tenant, can switch contexts to the Contoso Corp tenant because he is an external user there:

[image: User changes directory in Azure portal]

One the user has switched tenants, he'll be able to see any resources he's been granted access to in that tenant.

Comment: Hi, this user does not have an azure account. He is a hardware developer that need access to the iot hub to send messages there. My azure account inherits the users from my office 365 account.